# How to implement DATE_FORMAT in JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, jpql

How can i do this exact functionality in jpql

```
select *
from `attendence` 
where DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") = "10-2012"
```

i have used FUNCTION , but cannot implement same functionality as above.

Comment: Where is your JPQL that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

if you do a select like that, you destroy the potential index on date.

you can perhaps do something like :

`select * from attendence whre date>=:start and date<:end`
  start = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-10-01");
  end = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2012-11-01");